# Custom payment method isn't active

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I followed two guides to create a shipping method and a payment method, the two works normally, but I want to show the payment method only if the shipping method is selected, and because I think it's the best way, I put all the code in the same extension... now, the payment method doesn't appear in the frontend because is inactive.

And I don't understand why.

My code:

```
config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_ModuleName>
            <module>0.0.1</module>
        </Namespace_ModuleName>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <modulename>
                <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Helper</class>
            </modulename>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model</class>
            </modulename>
        </models>
    </global>
    <default>
        <carriers>
            <modulename>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Custom Title ship</title>
                <model>modulename/carrier_ship</model>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            </modulename>
        </carriers>
        <payment>
            <modulename>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Custom Title pay</title>
                <model>modulename/payment_pay</model>
                <order_status>processing</order_status>
                <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </modulename>
        </payment>
    </default>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <payment_method_is_active>
                <observers>
                    <modulename_payment_method_is_active>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>modulename/observer</class>
                        <method>paymentMethodIsActive</method>
                    </modulename_payment_method_is_active>
                </observers>
            </payment_method_is_active>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

System:

```
system.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers>
            <groups>
                <modulename translate="label" module="modulename">
                    <label>Custom Label Carrier</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort Order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Applicable Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific Countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                    </fields>
                </modulename>
            </groups>
        </carriers>
        <payment>
            <groups>
                <modulename translate="label" module="modulename">
                    <label>Custom Label Payment</label>
                    <sort_order>670</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <order_status translate="label">
                            <label>New order status</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status_processing</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </order_status>
                        <allowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from applicable countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </allowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Payment from Specific countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                    </fields>
                </modulename>
            </groups>
        </payment>
    </sections>
</config>
```

My model

```
Pay.php

<?php

class Namespace_ModuleName_Model_Payment_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'pay';


/* I tried with and without it
    protected $canUseCheckout    = true;
    public function validate()
    {
        parent::validate();
    }*/
}
```

I can see my custom payment method in the database:

```
path           value
.../active      1
```

But in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php
        public function isAvailable($quote = null)
        {
            $checkResult = new StdClass;
            $isActive = (bool)(int)$this->getConfigData('active', $quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null);
```

Here `$isActive` isn't 1, like the payment methods I can see in the frontend

Comment: Post your payment model                 `<model>modulename/payment_pay</model>`

Comment: It was at the end of the config files, but I put it separately

Comment: So it contains only     `protected $_code = 'pay';` ?

Comment: I tried the guide only for the payment method and it's works only with that, it's when I add the shipping method that I can't see it

Answer (score 0):

If your want to get your config field instead of configData... you get it like this:

```
$isActive = Mage::getStoreConfig('section/group/field'); // it returns 0 or 1

Frontend_type select of "adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno" return this:
0 = disabled, No
1 = enabled, Yes
```

Comment: I get the data to check the state of my payment method, what's I'm really want is to see it on the frontend, and for this, I need to set it active